# How to suppress WiX warnings without ICE code?

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.11

I am creating an installer that needs to be run multiple times in the same "new installation" configuration.
To achieve this, the following suppressions are set:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RegisterProduct Suppress="yes" />
  <PublishFeatures Suppress="yes" />
  <PublishProduct Suppress="yes" />
  <RegisterUser Suppress="yes" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

These however throw specific warnings of the type:

```
The action 'RegisterProduct' in the InstallExecuteSequence table is being suppressed.
```

Because of our policies, "acknowledged" warnings cannot show up in our build results, so they need to be entirely suppressed.

Warnings with an ICE code can be easily suppressed with `<SuppressSpecificWarnings>` and `<SuppressICEs>` in this case neither can be used.

`<SuppressAllWarnings>` also does not seem like an option, because other warnings generated by the installer must still be caught.

Does WiX provide an encapsulation to ignore warnings within the group?

Is there a way to at least capture these specific warnings and suppress them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors and warnings come from two places: Build and Validation.  ICEXX is validation and is controllable in Tools Settings when using Votive/Visual Studio.  The other warnings are build warnings and are controlled on the Build tab.   WiX allows you to set the warning level to None but this filters all warnings.  Visual Studio allows you to suppress specific warnings but WiX doesn't seem to have ever given the warnings individual code numbers so this isn't available.

Personally I would feel comfortable disabling or ignoring all warnings of either type. I only pay attention to errors.  This is based on 20+ years of Windows Installer experience.

Comment: I'll run that by the others, then.
iirc wix is on gh, so I'll consider notifying them as well. Thanks!